# Explicação do nome em php

Tags: html, input

Alguém poderia me explicar a diferença e onde posso modificar.:

```
$nome=$_POST['nome'];
```

Esse `$nome` eu sei que ele é padrão no caso for utilizar

```
<input type="text" name="nome">
```

Mais no caso, é obrigatório ter esse `"nome"` no `$_POST['nome']` ou poderei utilizar outros nomes?

Espero que tenham entendido.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, é justamente o contrário. O nome da variável `$nome`é totalmente livre, você pode nomeá-la como quiser ex. `$banana`, no entanto é boa pratica nomear as variáveis de forma a deixar claro o seu conteúdo.

Já, o valor na constante `$_POST`é dependente do valor setado parâmetro `name` no seu input html.

```
<!-- este "nome" será o valor incluso em $_POST[] -->
<input type="text" name="nome" />  

------------------------------------------
// contém o valor que o usuário digitar 
// no campo de texto com name="nome"
$_POST['nome']
```

Answer (score 2):

O array superglobal `$_POST` recebe dados enviados pelo método `HTTP` `POST`, por ser um `array` o mesmo possui chaves associadas a valores, no caso esse array superglobal associa o valor enviado pelo formulário  com o atributo `name` do `input` no seu caso `nome`, por exemplo você pode alterar o valor do atributo `name` do `input`, mas levar em conta que só será acessível em `$_POST` com o mesmo valor.

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="idade">
```

Ao tentar acessar `$_POST["nome"]` retornará `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Pode alterar se quiser, "_POST['nome']" é o nome da "mesma" variável declarada no PHP.